# Count if every nth range with a single criteria

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I have 1000 rows and have a single column, single criteria. I want to do `countif` for this data for a set of 50 rows at one time. How do I update the row number automatically so that I don't need to enter the range manually everytime?

*Additional information (from comments):*

I have a set of values (9-100) in a single column and 1000 rows. I want to use `>= 18` for every 50 rows so that it tells me how many cases within each set have a value greater than 18 . I do not want to manually enter the range in the `countif` function every time.

Comment: add example data please and a clear explanation of what you expect.

Comment: I have a set of values (9-100) in a single column and 1000 rows. I want to use >= 18 for every 50 rows so that it tells me how many cases within each set have a value greater than 18 . I do not want to manually enter the range in the countif function everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this one:

```
=COUNTIF((INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-1)*50+1&":A"&(ROW()-1)*50+50)),">="&18)
```

fill down 20 cells; then you will have `countif`of the every 50th range.